# how to negate a marker inside the test file

Tags: pytest

I'm running pytests on different controllers.
I have defined markers for each of my test targets

```
@pytest.mark.pcm33
@pytest.mark.pcm21
@pytest.mark.pcm62
@pytest.mark.pcm52
@pytest.mark.pcm61
def test_something():
```

So when I run `pytest -m pcm62` the test `test_something` is executed.

Now I have a test which must be executed on all my controllers, except for pcm62.
How can I negate this, so the test is always executed, except for pcm62, something like this

```
@pytest.notmark.pcm62
def test_something_except_for_pcm62():
```

But all that I can do is this:

```
@pytest.mark.pcm33
@pytest.mark.pcm21
#@pytest.mark.pcm62
@pytest.mark.pcm52
@pytest.mark.pcm61
def test_something_except_for_pcm62():
```

Notice that the more controllers I get to support, the longer my list of marker decorators gets.

`pytest -m "not pcm62"` does not do the trick because then I can not use the initial `test_something` in the same script.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what you're trying to achieve -- your example essentially contradicts itself. Could you provide the expected output? Or perhaps more context on how you're utilizing the markers?

Comment: Teejay Bruno I tried to make the context clearer.

Comment: Still not super clear on your issue. I suspect you're using markers when you should be using fixtures, possibly in combination with parametrization. I would recommend reading more of the pytest docs and taking a step back to re-evaluate your structure.